# WPF - what is the best way to implement a panel that hides?

Tags: wpf, hide, show, panels

I have a main application window that also implements a dock panel. At the bottom of one of the existing dock panels, I want to add a window that the user can hide or view at will. What's the best way to implement this? I can envision most of the code behind this, I just need to figure out the appropriate control for this window to appear when needed but still be discretely available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An [Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx) control might be what you are looking for. This is a ContentControl so you can use whatever Panel you want as the content.

Comment: Yup, that will do it alright. I appreciate the answer, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If you care about animations and Expanders, see the following link: If http://mattserbinski.com/blog/animating-expander